# Creating a "mailbox" like abstraction in Concurrent ML

Tags: smlnj, ml

I am trying to create a bounded "mailbox" like abstraction in Concurrent ML. My abstraction has 2 channels for taking values in (which are later stored in a list called "buffer") and for sending values out.

```
CM.make "$cml/cml.cm";
open CML;
fun mailbox inCh outCh buffer = let val inCh:int inCh =channel()
                                    val outCh:int outCh=channel()
                                    val buffer= [];
                                in 
                                buffer= (recv inCh);
                                fun loop x = choose[wrap (recvEvt inCh, loop ), wrap (sendEvt (outCh, (hd buffer)), buffer=tl(), loop x)];
                                end
fun main()=let 
            val iC:int iC=channel()
            val oC:int iC=channel()
            val buf=[];
            in
            spawn(fn()=> mailbox iC oC buf);
            RunCML.doit(main,NONE);
            ()
            end
```

This code seems correct to be syntactically but is giving a compilation error stating

```
mailboxtemp.sml:7.28 Error: syntax error: inserting  LET
mailboxtemp.sml:9.9 Error: syntax error: inserting  IN ID END

uncaught exception Compile [Compile: "syntax error"]
  raised at: ../compiler/Parse/main/smlfile.sml:15.24-15.46
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:44.55
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:296.17-296.20
```

Can someone please help me in finding out where I might have made a mistake?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is syntactically ill-formed and has numerous type errors in the bits that are well-formed.  Here are some suggestions:

1. Your `fun loop...` is a definition, but you list it in the middle of an expression.  Definitions must be at the top-level or within a `let` block (you can move it earlier, but unless you call `loop` somewhere, it won't do anything.
2. You don't need a semicolon at the end of a definition.  That might even be ill-formed.
3. The line `buffer= (recv inCh);` compares `buffer` (which you have defined to mean `[]`) with the result of calling `(recv inCh)`, then discards that result.  Other than for the side effect of calling `recv inCh`, that is entirely meaningless.
4. `val inCh:int inCh =channel()` is syntactically ill-formed.  I assume that you mean `val inCn : int = channel()`, but that doesn't type, because `channel()` does not return an `int`.

Please check http://www.eecs.ucf.edu/~leavens/learning-SML.html and work through one of the SML tutorials first.